# Delete PostgreSQL data and Library directories on Mac

Tags: macos, mac, postgresql

I want to completely clean PostgreSQL off of my Mac.  I ran the uninstaller and that removed everything but the data and Library directories.  I want to get rid of these two directories as well, but when I try an rm -r command, I get a permission error even though I am logged in as an administrator.  How can I get these directories off of my computer?

Answer (score 0):

The Mac OS X administrator user has the right to *get* full access rights. It doesn't run with those rights all the time.

To ask for full rights for a command you use `sudo`.

So you will want:

```
sudo rm -rf /path/to/Library/PostgreSQL
```

Of course, that'll completely and unrecoverably delete all the data in all databases in that PostgreSQL install, but that seems to be what you want.